# I am trying to install python module HTTP

Tags: python, http, request

I am trying to install python module "HTTP" but this error is coming

```
pip install HTTP
Collecting HTTP
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/91/a9260805e532e33df273b8f7dffad5c51693f8f9ba5f86bedcf42a7f22eb/http-0.02.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\pip-install-u99l10q0\HTTP\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import http
      File "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\pip-install-u99l10q0\HTTP\http\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from request import Request
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Request'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\pip-install-u99l10q0\HTTP\
```

Comment: This is a beta project, unmaintained since 2012, and evidently has reproducible bugs that prevent it from installing. Consider using [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP module is already present in python 3.7 ([Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/http.html)). You don't need to install it.

Answer (score 2):

You might have an out of date setuptools
What you could try is to run the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```